# Qt5 custom widget - Curved slider

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I'm starting my next electronics project which is to create my own version of Google's Nest Thermostat. I like the whole circular dial for temperature selection and I've been having a think about how to create this myself. GUI programming is not my area of expertise (CLI all the way!).

So far I'm think along one of two lines, both involving custom widgets:

1. Create a widget that inherits from the pushbutton class. This subclass will contain lots of buttons, one for each step in the temperature scale, arranged in a 3/4 circle.
2. Create a widget that inherits from the slider class, defining an object that is curved around 3/4 of a circle. Each step is a temperature.

Now... I have no idea if these are practical solutions to this problem or if there is a much easier way of doing this. I've had a look at the style sheets and I don't *THINK* that is going to do it. I've had a root around Google for anything similar and not found anything yet; that said, AnalogWidgets from [3electrons](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/AnalogWidgets?content=87780) at least creates dials, but these are for output rather than input.

Comment: This sort of thing is laughably easy in QtQuick, and painfully difficult using QtWidgets - any reason why you haven't considered that?  As it stands this question is far too broad for SO (there's numerous ways of achieving what you're asking), so you'll need to do more research and narrow your question down into something more specific.

Comment: Then I'll have a look at QtQuick. Not come across that yet. I was too focused on how to do it with widgets. Thanks.

Comment: [QGraphicsView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html) is also worth to mention. If you have to use widgets (mixing QML and QWidget technology has many limitations) or you don't have enough time to learn how things work in QML, QGraphicsView offers some great functionality for flexible UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out yesterday and it works rather nicely if you want to simulate the nest thermostat in an app this includes the js and SVG image:
https://www.svidget.io/examples/nestthermostat

HTML snippet:

```
<object id="nestThermostatWidget" role="svidget" data="nestThermostatWidget.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="400" height="400">
<param name="targetTemp" value="77" />
<param name="ambientTemp" value="80" />
<param name="unit" value="F" />
<param name="state" value="cooling" />
<param name="showLeaf" value="1" />
<param name="awayMode" value="0" /> 
</object>
```

Comment: A link can be useful but please also post relevant information from the link, otherwise if the link dies your answer is redundant. Cheers

Comment: will add the SVG when I get to a PC.